# Is it possible to create input scanner between String value Java Console?

Tags: java, input, console-application, java.util.scanner

I try to custom my Java Console Application, but I have a problem when I try to show it in Command Prompt will appear input Scanner between String...

```
int a;  
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Input value of a: " + (a = scan.nextInt()) + " !");
```

Anyone can resolve this problem, help me.... 
thank you

Comment: Whats the problem here ? For me your code is working fine.

Comment: It didn't work....
for example in my cmd can showing,
Input value of a: [my input] !... there are texts after my input

Comment: "Input value of a: " + (a = scan.nextInt()) + " !"
that code the problem, any solution...

Comment: @zbyszekt is right. It is working fine. Did you try to insert your value?

Comment: Please copy/take a screen of your results and show us. @user8322851

Comment: @user8322851 your code is absolutely fine, but you must be getting input prompt before the string `"Input value of a: "`, right ??? and now wandering why it happened. ;)

Comment: exactly no error, and work fine... but it was not my expectation.... , thank you brother

Comment: @user8322851 then what did you expect ? can you provide more detail on it?

Comment: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GTqZQFN.png this is the code

Comment: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GTr1N1h.png, and this is the result
nothing happens

Comment: Did you try to write number and hit Enter in console ?

Comment: @user8322851 that's what i tried to confirm in my older comments. Don't worry, now I got your question and apparently an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First of all, your code runs as it is coded not as it is expected.
As your output is blank, and you are wandering why the prompt has not come yet for asking the user input, then let me tell you one thing, that it is actually asking you to enter some input right there. As soon as, you will enter, you shall see the next line of your output will be..

`Input value of a: (whatEverYouEntered)`

So your final output would be, (strictly as per your code..)

---

```
 F:/SMK/oop>javac Main.java
 F:/SMK/oop>5 (assumed you type 5 and press enter)
 F:/SMK/oop>Input value of a: 5
```

**2.** If you think that your code should print `Input value of a:` line fist and then you will enter the value, then you'll have to make changes as below.

```
int a;  
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input value of a: ");
a = scan.nextInt();
```

**3.** And if you are really curious about the reason why your code was behaving like that..then read this..

I would say, change your code as stated below and then run, you might get a hint, otherwise I'll explain later.

```
public static void main(String[] s) {
    int a = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input value of a: " + (a = new Main().getVal()) + " !");
    System.out.println("A = " + a);
}
public int getVal(){
    System.out.println("getVal called first.");
    return 5;
}
```

### See the output now, it shall be.

```
 F:/SMK/oop>javac Main.java
 F:/SMK/oop>getVal called first.
 F:/SMK/oop>Input value of a: 5
```

The reason is, when JVM interprets `System.out.println("Input value of a: " + (a = new Main().getVal()) + " !");` this as a single statement, and to execute it must be complete... so how will it get complete?--> By assigning the value of `a`. and to do so, it must call `getVal()` function before printing anything, right?

Exactly the same is happening in your code, as your print statement will be executed after the call of `scan.nextInt()` and `nextInt()` immediately asks for user input without showing any message in console. And once the input is provided, it will assign the value to `a` and now the print statement is actually complete and ready to execute. And hence, you would see the print output after the input prompt.

Hope it gives you good idea about java and programming language as well.

Happy coding :)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks for pointing out, actually while code formatting some `ctrl + z` messed up the things.. thanks again. !